# stop all videos when a new video is played in react native

Tags: react-native

i want to stop all video when new video is playing. I am using react-native-video library to play video. If I play a video it starts playing, if I click on another video in the list it also starts playing, both videos are getting played at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Keep an array of video play/pause state to ensure that only one can be true at a time. Then update the Video component paused property on update.

Comment: shall you share example